# Android : Customize auto complete textview's list using theme

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-theme

I want to customize my autocomplete textview's drop-down list. I have used android:dropDownVerticalOffset="10dp" for getting the list down, now I have to use particular theme for the list. Below is the theme I want to use.

[image: Theme for autocomplete textview]

I tried using android:dropDownAnchor="", but there is no success at all. Please help in overcoming this problem.

Comment: can you give us the xml theme?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Custom Adapter to give the AutoCompleteTextView a custom view.

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    ArrayList<String> search;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter() {
        super();
        search = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return search.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PcsContact getItem(int index) {
        return search.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {           
        //use ur custom view here. Inflate the view from xml.
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) { 

                results.values = search.clone();
                results.count = search.size();

                return results;
            }
        };
    }       
}
```

Use Spannable String to set the not typed result be bold
Ask me if any more help is needed.